# Group by having for month

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

If I need to display in SQL product names which were bought at least once in a month with total sum greater than 100 points for that month of a period 2014-01-01 to 2015-12-31, is this the right approach?

```
select b.ProductName, Sum(a.RequestedAmount) as summ
from ProductRequest a
join product b on a.productid=b.productid
where a.AppDate >= '2014-01-01' and a.AppDate <= '2015-12-31'
group by b.ProductName, month (a.appDate)
having Sum(a.RequestedAmount) > 100
```

Comment: Is this giving the right result?

Comment: General GROUP BY tip. Have same columns in select list (except arguments to set functions), as in group by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is close but not quite right.  The problem is that `month()` returns a month number from 1 to 12.  Your time span exceeds year, so you need to take the year into account:

```
select p.ProductName, Sum(pr.RequestedAmount) as summ
from ProductRequest pr join
     Product p
     on pr.productid = p.productid
where pr.AppDate >= '2014-01-01' and pr.AppDate <= '2015-12-31'
group by p.ProductName, year(pr.appDate), month(pr.appDate)
having sum(pr.RequestedAmount) > 100;
```

Notes:

- When using table aliases, abbreviations for the table names are much easier to follow than arbitrary letters.
- Often, you would want to include the month when the spending occurred.
- The difference with your query is the `year()` in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT b.ProductName, month (a.appDate), Sum(a.RequestedAmount) as summ
from ProductRequest a
join product b on a.productid=b.productid
where a.AppDate>='2014-01-01' and a.AppDate<='2015-12-31'
group by b.ProductName, month (a.appDate)
) x
where x.summ>100
```